# Have 101 rep, can't answer protected question that requires 10 rep

Tags: bug, reputation, protected-questions

It is either a glitch or a wording glitch, but I can't answer protected questions that say they only require 10 rep

Comment: [Here's a duplicate](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1340/why-cant-i-answer-this-protected-question-even-with-my-bonus-network-rep) - basically, it means you need to have earned ten reputation on this site specifically. More information in the linked question.